# PHP: preg_split with the first described char

Tags: php, preg-split

I have a string like this:

```
bla bla: [blabla: "bla"]
```

I want to explode it by the char `":"` and as you can see I have this char in two position but I want to split it by only the first one
So the result I want is:

```
1- bla bla
2- [blabla: "bla"]
```

How can I achieve this using preg_split ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
list($before, $after) = explode(':', $source, 2);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ty :). But can you explain it please ?

Comment: Please refer the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php.

It says:
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] ) 
If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for,

```
$string = 'bla bla: [blabla: "bla"]';
$arr = preg_split("#:#", $string,'2');
print_r($arr);
```

> **limit**
>   If specified, then only substrings up to **limit** are returned with the rest of the string being placed in the last substring. A **limit** of -1, 0 or NULL means "no limit" and, as is standard across PHP, you can use NULL to skip to the **flags** parameter.

Working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10fb719613ff2d5cc2acd9ba97ec9bf046b78ffe).